# My project doesn't see the HMS Map Kit Api Key where am I making a mistake?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

My project doesn't see the HMS Map Kit Api Key where am I making a mistake?

Hi,

I did api key integration as shown in the dumps, but I get the error api key integration is not done?

Comment: Can you show error in details please. And the how did you add the api key in your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to obtain the API key. Please follow the steps listed in the article.

**1.    Obtain the API key from the HUAWEI Developers.**

a)  Register as a developer and complete identity verification.

b)  Go to **Console** > **HMS API Services** > **My APIs** > **New project** to create a project.

c)  Click **Add API from library** and find the required API in **API Library**.

d)  Create a credential before using an API.

- Go to **Console** > **HMS API Services** > **My APIs** > **Add API from library**. In **API Library**, find and click **Map Kit**.
- Click **Enable**. The API is successfully enabled.
- Go to **HMS API Services** > **Credentials** and click Create credential.
- Click **API key**. The API key is successfully created.

**Check the screenshot below.**
[image]

**2.    Obtain the API key automatically generated when you create an app in AppGallery Connect.**

a)  Sign in to AppGallery Connect and click **My projects**.

b)  Find your app project, and click the app name.

c)  Go to **Project Setting** > **General information**. In the **App information** area, click the icon next to **API key**. The API key will then be copied to the clipboard.

**Check the screenshot below.**
[image]

I recommend you check out [the official documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-Guides-V5/web-api-introduction-0000001050162828-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050162828__section1359519285410). For more on HUAWEI Map Kit, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-MapKit).